# Communication between a Cocoa and a C# application

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa, ipc

I have an OS X server application written in Objective-C. I'd like to write a client in C# which runs on Windows systems.

Which is the simplest way to do the communication between the two applications?

I'm familiar with NSConnection, and I'd like to use something similar.

*The application is a very simple auction game. The clients passes integers as bids to the server, which processes them and notify the clients about the state of the auction (current best bid and offer and such).*